# Function A(t,T) in one-factor Hull-White model

Tags: interest-rates, hullwhite

I am struggling with Hull-White model now and have the following question: in the lecture notes under the link below I see how A(t,T) and B(t,T) are being derived. This requires the solution of ordinary differential equations. With B(t,T) it is more or less clear, still I don't understand how the author comes up with the formula (5) which expresses A(t,T).

Would be grateful for any hint.

http://www.math.nyu.edu/~benartzi/Slides10.3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it comes directly from integration when I look at the slides. As per your slide we have that A(t,T) should satisfy:

$A_t − \theta(t)AB + 0.5 σ^2 AB^2 = 0$.

Simplifying above condition (by bringing all the A terms to the left side) we get:

$ \frac{1}{A}dA = \theta(t)B - 0.5 σ^2 B^2$

now we integrate both sides:
$ln(A) = -\int_t^T \theta(s)B(s) ds + 0.5 \sigma^2 \int B^2 ds$

**edited the signs of the integrals**. Note the signs of the integral as we are dealing with a **backward ODE** instead of a regular forward ODE. This because we have **terminal condition** A(T,T) and B(T,T) instead of **initial conditions.**

You already were able to derive the formula for B. Stick it in and do the integration on the $B^2$ part. that should give you the answer as provided in the slides.

Comment: Dear mbison! Thanks for your very useful answer. Still I have a question to it. Everything is logical, but if we take exponential of both sides in ln(A)=∫Ttθ(s)B(s)ds−0.5σ2∫B2ds, the first term on the RHS will still have no minus... That is confusing... Am I missing something? Do you have any idea how the author comes to the solution in the lecture notes?

Comment: @QuackQuack , There is a Different approach in this context. you can use $P(t,T)=\mathbb{E}^Q[exp(-\int_{t}^{T}r_u du|\mathcal{F}_t]$ .But you should calculate $-\int_{t}^{T}r_u du$ at first.

Comment: @QuackQuack: I see where the confusion with the + and - sign comes from. The reason is because normally ODEs go forward in time with a **initial** condition. However equation for bond is stated with a **terminal** condition $P(T,T) =1$, therefore you solve a **backward ODE**. So actually the author of your paper is absolutely correct with their signs and I actually screwed up the + and - sign in my answer. so it should be $ln(A) = - \int_{t}^T \theta(s)B(s)ds + 0.5\sigma^2 \int B^2 ds$ (due to the fact that you are solving the ODE backwards in time instead of forward).

Comment: @QuakQuack: might be helpful to look at page 9 of http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/HOA/JAMDS/8/11.pdf on page 9 of this paper they solve the same backward ode but for the regular Vasicek model. Concepts and maths are very similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: @mbison: thank you very much, now it works

Comment: @quackquack: most welcome.

Comment: Hi, I also have some confusion here. If we look at final equation it says to solve ln(A) we need to provide one of the input as ln(P(0,T)/P(0,t)). If my t =0 so my P(0,10) = 1 (10 years maturity ZCB) but what should be my value for P(0,0) ? Apologies, if I am confusing further.